# getting current leader of election recipe in kazoo

Tags: python, apache-zookeeper, kazoo

I am able to get current contenders using `election.lock._get_sorted_children()` and respective identifiers using `election.lock.contenders()`. But `election.lock.contenders()` also sorts the list, so will `election.lock.contenders()[0]` always be the leader?

Note, `election = zk.Election("/path", "uuid")` where `zk` is the `KazooClient`

Is there any better way to verify the leader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kazoo follows zookepeers recommendation that the node with smallest index should acquire the lock. The [`Lock::_inner_acquire`](https://github.com/python-zk/kazoo/blob/master/kazoo/recipe/lock.py#L206) ensures that the lock is acquired by the smallest index, by always waiting for predecessors to finish before acquiring lock. Hence, `election.lock.contenders()[0]` will always be the leader (unless the list is empty of-course).